# Printing a text document using Java

Tags: java, printing

Alright, I have made a program that makes a text file. The text file is a different size every time the program is ran. I simply just want to add a print button that allows the user to print out the text file to a printer. I made a button with an action listener that brings up my print class. It is almost working except it only prints one page with my text displayed in horizontal columns extremely small. I think my problem has something to do with my printJob setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class PrintingClass implements Printable {

    // Global variables
    int[] pageBreaks;
    String [] textLines;
    static String fileName;

    public static void print(String filename){
        fileName = filename;
        PrintingClass object = new PrintingClass();

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        job.setPrintable(object);

        Boolean ok = job.printDialog();

        if (ok) {
            try {
                 job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
             /* The job did not successfully complete */
            }
        }

    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {

       Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);
       FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
       int lineHeight = metrics.getHeight();

       if (pageBreaks == null) {
           initTextLines();
           int linesPerPage = (int)(pf.getImageableHeight()/lineHeight);
           System.out.println("Lines per page = " + linesPerPage);
           int numBreaks = (textLines.length-1)/linesPerPage;
           System.out.println("number of pages = " + numBreaks);
           pageBreaks = new int[numBreaks];
           for (int b=0; b<numBreaks; b++) {
               pageBreaks[b] = (b+1)*linesPerPage; 
           }
       }

       if (pageIndex > pageBreaks.length) {
           return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
       }

       /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
        * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
        * Since we are drawing text we
        */
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

       /* Draw each line that is on this page.
        * Increment 'y' position by lineHeight for each line.
        */
       int y = 0; 
       int start = (pageIndex == 0) ? 0 : pageBreaks[pageIndex-1];
       int end   = (pageIndex == pageBreaks.length)
                        ? textLines.length : pageBreaks[pageIndex];
       for (int line=start; line<end; line++) {
           y += lineHeight;
           g.drawString(textLines[line], 0, y);
       }

       /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
       return PAGE_EXISTS;
   }

    /**
     * This will initialize the textLines[] variable
     * and read in my file
     * @param fileName
     */
    public void initTextLines(){
        // Get file size
        int fileSize = counter();

        // Initialize textLine
        textLines = new String[fileSize];

        // Read text to set lines
        BufferedReader file;
        try {
            file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = null;
            int x = 0;
            while((line = file.readLine()) != null){
                textLines[x] = line;
                x++;
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will simply count the size of the file
     * and return it
     * @return
     */
    public int counter(){
        int count = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while(file.readLine() != null){
                count++;
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Most of this code comes straight from Javas own tutorial page. Thank you.

Comment: Try a larger Monospace font.  Your pageBreaks code calculates an incorrect number of pages.

Comment: Thanks for commenting back. Sadly this didn't change anything. After it calculates the page number I have it print out to the console which gives me the correct page number (3 pages at 10 size font). Any other possible suggestions?